# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PdfController] does not exist but it is there and syntax is correct

Tags: php, routes, laravel-8

I have read many posts on similar problem... nothing works.

1/ I installed the package with composer.

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
```

2/ Created app/Http/Controllers/PdfController.php

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
 use PDF;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
 class PdfController extends Controller
 {
     public function index() 
     {
         $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.sample', [
             'title' => 'CodeAndDeploy.com Laravel Pdf Tutorial',
             'description' => 'This is an example Laravel pdf tutorial.',
             'footer' => 'by <a href="https://codeanddeploy.com">codeanddeploy.com</a>'
         ]);
 
         return $pdf->download('sample.pdf');
     }
 }
```

3/ added the route in web.php (the syntax works for my other routes)

```
 // pdf
 //Route::get('/pdf', [PdfController::class, 'index']); (originally)
 Route::get('/pdf', 'App\Http\Controllers\PdfController@index')->name('pdf');
```

4/ cleaned as much as possible

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan optimize
 php artisan route:clear
```

5/ if I run xxx/pdf or php artisan route:list, I get the error

```
 Target class [App\Http\Controllers\PdfController] does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes strange things happen.  My Mac was not saving files... so although I could see the controller as saved in VSCode... it was not saved on disk... so weird! After rebooting, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan optimize` is actually for caching, rather than just clearing - I wouldn't recommend using it during development.

```
php artisan cache:clear // Flushes application cache
php artisan route:clear // Clears compiled routes
php artisan view:clear // Clears compiled views
```

The above deal with views, routes and cache data, but you likely need a way to clear your cached php class list (as `PdfController` is not being detected, but the file exists).

```
composer dumpautoload // Regenerates list of autoloaded classes
```

[dumpautoload @ composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload)